# Bind checkbox to label fontweight with value converter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, valueconverter

I want to make label that have FontWeight attribute dependent on checkbox.
If checkbox is checked then label font weight is bold, if not - then font weight is normal. I decided to bind FontWeight attribute in Label with Checkbox and add converter.

Here is screen what I want to achieve (text on bottom should be bolded when Bold is checked)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY6hn.png)

I created all the logic and binding but when I click on Bold checkbox nothing happends.

Here is what I have so far
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window ...
 ...
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="custom" TrueValue="Bold" FalseValue="Normal" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
...
   <CheckBox Name="BoldField" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold">Bold</CheckBox>
   <Label Name="text" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    FontWeight="{Binding BoldField, Converter={StaticResource custom}}" />
...
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace Wpf03
{
    public class BoolToValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
    {
        public T FalseValue { get; set; }
        public T TrueValue { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return FalseValue;
            else
                return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
        }
    }

    public class BoolToStringConverter : BoolToValueConverter<FontWeight> { }


    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with different converters but no result. Why my converter is never called? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `Name` of the `CheckBox` as the Binding Path

instead you need to specify the `IsChecked` property:

```
   <CheckBox Name="BoldField" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold">Bold</CheckBox>
   <Label Name="text" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    FontWeight="{Binding ElementName=BoldField, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource custom}}" />
```